# Animación con CSS

Tags: html, css, css3

Necesito animar varios div y que uno entre después de otro, he probado este código, el problema es que antes de empezar la animación, los que tienen "animation-delay" se muestran en pantalla al cargar la página y cuando pasan los ms que le corresponden por el delay dejan de verse y entonces se muestran con la animación, necesitaria que no se mostrara nada antes de realizar la animacion y que fueran apareciendo de forma progresiva.

He probado a poner desde el principio opacity 0 pero al finalizar la animación desaparece el div.

```
.slide-in1{
    animation:fading 1s 
}
.slide-in2{
    animation:fading 1s;
    animation-delay: 100ms;
}
.slide-in3{
    animation:fading 1s;
    animation-delay: 200ms;
}
.slide-in4{
    animation:fading 1s;
    animation-delay: 300ms;
}
@keyframes fading{
    0%{
        display:none;
        opacity:0
    }
    100%{
        display:block;
        opacity:1
    }
}

<table style="border-collapse: collapse;">
            <tr class="clasif slide-in1">
                <th class="pos"><span class="posnumber">1</span></th>
                <th class="name">Javier Cuenca Martín</th>
                <th class="pts"><span class="ptsnumber">328</span></th>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 5px;"></tr>
            <tr class="clasif slide-in2">
                <th class="pos"><span class="posnumber">2</span></th>
                <th class="name">Javier Cuenca Martín</th>
                <th class="pts"><span class="ptsnumber">328</span></th>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 5px;"></tr>
            <tr class="clasif slide-in3">
                <th class="pos"><span class="posnumber">3</span></th>
                <th class="name">Javier Cuenca Martín</th>
                <th class="pts"><span class="ptsnumber">328</span></th>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 5px;"></tr>
            <tr class="clasif slide-in4">
                <th class="pos"><span class="posnumber">4</span></th>
                <th class="name">Javier Cuenca Martín</th>
                <th class="pts"><span class="ptsnumber">328</span></th>
            </tr>

        </table>
```

Comment: Deberias agregar tu HTML

Comment: ya esta añadido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes hacerlo así:

- Para arrancar *"invisible"* agregamos a todos los `.slide-ini` la regla `opacity: 0;`
- Para preservar el estado al finalizar la animación agregamos [`animation-fill-mode: forwards`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode#valores)

  > **`forwards`**: El objeto sobre el que se aplica la animación quedará con los valores y estilos que le aplique el último keyframe de la ejecución de la animación. El último valor dependerá del valor de `animation-direction` y `animation-iteration-count`

#### Ejemplo:

```css
.slide-in1 {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fading 1s forwards;
}

.slide-in2 {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fading 1s 100ms forwards;
}

.slide-in3 {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fading 1s 200ms forwards;
}

.slide-in4 {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fading 1s 300ms forwards;
}

@keyframes fading {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tr class="clasif slide-in1">
    <th class="pos"><span class="posnumber">1</span></th>
    <th class="name">Javier Cuenca Martín</th>
    <th class="pts"><span class="ptsnumber">328</span></th>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 5px;"></tr>
  <tr class="clasif slide-in2">
    <th class="pos"><span class="posnumber">2</span></th>
    <th class="name">Javier Cuenca Martín</th>
    <th class="pts"><span class="ptsnumber">328</span></th>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 5px;"></tr>
  <tr class="clasif slide-in3">
    <th class="pos"><span class="posnumber">3</span></th>
    <th class="name">Javier Cuenca Martín</th>
    <th class="pts"><span class="ptsnumber">328</span></th>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 5px;"></tr>
  <tr class="clasif slide-in4">
    <th class="pos"><span class="posnumber">4</span></th>
    <th class="name">Javier Cuenca Martín</th>
    <th class="pts"><span class="ptsnumber">328</span></th>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Si quieres que solo se muestre de manera progresiva, quítale el `animation-delay` y juega con el fading solamente.

```css
.slide-in1{
    animation:fading 1s 
}
.slide-in2{
    animation:fading 3s;
 
}
.slide-in3{
    animation:fading 5s;

}
.slide-in4{
    animation:fading 7s;
    
}
@keyframes fading{
    0%{
        display:none;
        opacity:0
    }
    100%{
        display:block;
        opacity:1
    }
}
```

```html
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;">
        <tr class="clasif slide-in1">
            <th class="pos"><span class="posnumber">1</span></th>
            <th class="name">Javier Cuenca Martín</th>
            <th class="pts"><span class="ptsnumber">328</span></th>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 5px;"></tr>
        <tr class="clasif slide-in2">
            <th class="pos"><span class="posnumber">2</span></th>
            <th class="name">Javier Cuenca Martín</th>
            <th class="pts"><span class="ptsnumber">328</span></th>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 5px;"></tr>
        <tr class="clasif slide-in3">
            <th class="pos"><span class="posnumber">3</span></th>
            <th class="name">Javier Cuenca Martín</th>
            <th class="pts"><span class="ptsnumber">328</span></th>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 5px;"></tr>
        <tr class="clasif slide-in4">
            <th class="pos"><span class="posnumber">4</span></th>
            <th class="name">Javier Cuenca Martín</th>
            <th class="pts"><span class="ptsnumber">328</span></th>
        </tr>

    </table>
```